# Not able to create large size HubTile in WP8

Tags: c#, visual-studio, xaml, windows-phone-8, windows-phone-toolkit

```
<toolkit:HubTile
                    Background="Red" 
                    Source="/Assets/MedicineImg/crocin.jpg"
                     Title="Crocin"
                    HorizontalAlignment="Left"
                    VerticalAlignment="Top"
                    Margin="0,0,0,0"
                    Height="400"
                    Width="400"
                   />
```

i am trying to enlarge my hubtile, but only its frame enlarges , all its animations and the image doesn't enlarge , can anyone suggest a logic for enlarging my entire Hubtile with all its contents  to 400 x 400 .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As far as I know, you can't just change the width and height of a HubTile that easily (just by setting the properties). You need to dig into the style of the control and not only change the width and height but also make sure that all the animations are properly changed, too.

[I wrote a blog post in 2011](http://igrali.com/2011/08/19/how-to-use-the-hubtile-control/) about changing it to 300x300 (disclaimer - not only is it my post, but it was also written a long time ago, so it may not work 100%) but it would definitely be a great start for what you need - you could easily modify it to work for you and for whatever size you need.

EDIT: Obviously things changed since 2011. :)

Now the Hubtile uses enum of tile sizes and two converters, width and height to do the conversion to exact width and height values.

There are two options here. The first is to use your own converters and add the tile sizes you need which would probably be a cleaner solution. The quick and dirty solution is to just remove the value converters and the use of the tile size from the style, and hardcode the values in a way which will preserve ratios, but will use 400x400 size.

Here's the style.

```
<Style x:Key="HubTileStyle1" TargetType="toolkit:HubTile">
    <Setter Property="Height" Value="400"/>
    <Setter Property="Width" Value="400"/>
    <Setter Property="Background" Value="{StaticResource PhoneAccentBrush}"/>
    <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="#FFFFFFFF"/>
    <Setter Property="Template">
        <Setter.Value>
            <ControlTemplate TargetType="toolkit:HubTile">
                <Border x:Name="Container" Width="400" Height="400">
                    <Border.Resources>
                        <CubicEase x:Key="HubTileEaseOut" EasingMode="EaseOut"/>
                    </Border.Resources>
                    <VisualStateManager.VisualStateGroups>
                        <VisualStateGroup x:Name="ImageStates">
                            <VisualStateGroup.Transitions>
                                <VisualTransition x:Name="ExpandedToSemiexpanded" From="Expanded" GeneratedDuration="0:0:0.85" To="Semiexpanded">
                                    <Storyboard>
                                        <DoubleAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetProperty="(UIElement.RenderTransform).(CompositeTransform.TranslateY)" Storyboard.TargetName="TitlePanel">
                                            <EasingDoubleKeyFrame EasingFunction="{StaticResource HubTileEaseOut}" KeyTime="0:0:0.0" Value="-400"/>
                                            <EasingDoubleKeyFrame EasingFunction="{StaticResource HubTileEaseOut}" KeyTime="0:0:0.85" Value="-182.64"/>
                                        </DoubleAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                                        <DoubleAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetProperty="RotationX" Storyboard.TargetName="ViewportProjection">
                                            <EasingDoubleKeyFrame EasingFunction="{StaticResource HubTileEaseOut}" KeyTime="0:0:0.0" Value="0.0"/>
                                        </DoubleAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                                    </Storyboard>
                                </VisualTransition>
                                <VisualTransition x:Name="SemiexpandedToExpanded" From="Semiexpanded" GeneratedDuration="0:0:0.85" To="Expanded">
                                    <Storyboard>
                                        <DoubleAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetProperty="(UIElement.RenderTransform).(CompositeTransform.TranslateY)" Storyboard.TargetName="TitlePanel">
                                            <EasingDoubleKeyFrame EasingFunction="{StaticResource HubTileEaseOut}" KeyTime="0:0:0.0" Value="-182.64"/>
                                            <EasingDoubleKeyFrame EasingFunction="{StaticResource HubTileEaseOut}" KeyTime="0:0:0.85" Value="-400"/>
                                        </DoubleAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                                    </Storyboard>
                                </VisualTransition>
                                <VisualTransition x:Name="SemiexpandedToCollapsed" From="Semiexpanded" GeneratedDuration="0:0:0.85" To="Collapsed">
                                    <Storyboard>
                                        <DoubleAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetProperty="(UIElement.RenderTransform).(CompositeTransform.TranslateY)" Storyboard.TargetName="TitlePanel">
                                            <EasingDoubleKeyFrame EasingFunction="{StaticResource HubTileEaseOut}" KeyTime="0:0:0.0" Value="-182.64"/>
                                            <EasingDoubleKeyFrame EasingFunction="{StaticResource HubTileEaseOut}" KeyTime="0:0:0.85" Value="0.0"/>
                                        </DoubleAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                                    </Storyboard>
                                </VisualTransition>
                                <VisualTransition x:Name="CollapsedToExpanded" From="Collapsed" GeneratedDuration="0:0:0.85" To="Expanded">
                                    <Storyboard>
                                        <DoubleAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetProperty="(UIElement.RenderTransform).(CompositeTransform.TranslateY)" Storyboard.TargetName="TitlePanel">
                                            <EasingDoubleKeyFrame EasingFunction="{StaticResource HubTileEaseOut}" KeyTime="0:0:0.0" Value="0.0"/>
                                            <EasingDoubleKeyFrame EasingFunction="{StaticResource HubTileEaseOut}" KeyTime="0:0:0.85" Value="-400"/>
                                        </DoubleAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                                    </Storyboard>
                                </VisualTransition>
                                <VisualTransition x:Name="ExpandedToFlipped" From="Expanded" GeneratedDuration="0:0:0.85" To="Flipped">
                                    <Storyboard>
                                        <DoubleAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetProperty="(UIElement.RenderTransform).(CompositeTransform.TranslateY)" Storyboard.TargetName="TitlePanel">
                                            <EasingDoubleKeyFrame EasingFunction="{StaticResource HubTileEaseOut}" KeyTime="0:0:0.0" Value="-400"/>
                                        </DoubleAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                                        <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetProperty="(UIElement.Visibility)" Storyboard.TargetName="Image">
                                            <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0:0:0.185" Value="Collapsed"/>
                                        </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                                        <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetProperty="(UIElement.Visibility)" Storyboard.TargetName="BackPanel">
                                            <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0:0:0.185" Value="Visible"/>
                                        </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                                        <DoubleAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetProperty="RotationX" Storyboard.TargetName="ViewportProjection">
                                            <EasingDoubleKeyFrame EasingFunction="{StaticResource HubTileEaseOut}" KeyTime="0:0:0.0" Value="0.0"/>
                                            <EasingDoubleKeyFrame EasingFunction="{StaticResource HubTileEaseOut}" KeyTime="0:0:0.85" Value="180.0"/>
                                        </DoubleAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                                    </Storyboard>
                                </VisualTransition>
                                <VisualTransition x:Name="FlippedToExpanded" From="Flipped" GeneratedDuration="0:0:0.85" To="Expanded">
                                    <Storyboard>
                                        <DoubleAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetProperty="(UIElement.RenderTransform).(CompositeTransform.TranslateY)" Storyboard.TargetName="TitlePanel">
                                            <EasingDoubleKeyFrame EasingFunction="{StaticResource HubTileEaseOut}" KeyTime="0:0:0.0" Value="-400"/>
                                        </DoubleAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                                        <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetProperty="(UIElement.Visibility)" Storyboard.TargetName="Image">
                                            <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0:0:0.185" Value="Visible"/>
                                        </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                                        <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetProperty="(UIElement.Visibility)" Storyboard.TargetName="BackPanel">
                                            <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0:0:0.185" Value="Collapsed"/>
                                        </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                                        <DoubleAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetProperty="RotationX" Storyboard.TargetName="ViewportProjection">
                                            <EasingDoubleKeyFrame EasingFunction="{StaticResource HubTileEaseOut}" KeyTime="0:0:0.0" Value="180.0"/>
                                            <EasingDoubleKeyFrame EasingFunction="{StaticResource HubTileEaseOut}" KeyTime="0:0:0.85" Value="360.0"/>
                                        </DoubleAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                                    </Storyboard>
                                </VisualTransition>
                            </VisualStateGroup.Transitions>
                            <VisualState x:Name="Expanded">
                                <Storyboard>
                                    <DoubleAnimation Duration="0" To="-400" Storyboard.TargetProperty="(UIElement.RenderTransform).(CompositeTransform.TranslateY)" Storyboard.TargetName="TitlePanel"/>
                                    <DoubleAnimation Duration="0" To="0.0" Storyboard.TargetProperty="RotationX" Storyboard.TargetName="ViewportProjection"/>
                                    <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetProperty="(UIElement.Visibility)" Storyboard.TargetName="Image">
                                        <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0:0:0" Value="Visible"/>
                                    </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                                </Storyboard>
                            </VisualState>
                            <VisualState x:Name="Semiexpanded">
                                <Storyboard>
                                    <DoubleAnimation Duration="0" To="-182.64" Storyboard.TargetProperty="(UIElement.RenderTransform).(CompositeTransform.TranslateY)" Storyboard.TargetName="TitlePanel"/>
                                </Storyboard>
                            </VisualState>
                            <VisualState x:Name="Collapsed"/>
                            <VisualState x:Name="Flipped">
                                <Storyboard>
                                    <DoubleAnimation Duration="0" To="400" Storyboard.TargetProperty="(UIElement.RenderTransform).(CompositeTransform.TranslateY)" Storyboard.TargetName="TitlePanel"/>
                                    <DoubleAnimation Duration="0" To="180.0" Storyboard.TargetProperty="RotationX" Storyboard.TargetName="ViewportProjection"/>
                                    <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetProperty="(UIElement.Visibility)" Storyboard.TargetName="Image">
                                        <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0:0:0" Value="Collapsed"/>
                                    </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                                    <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetProperty="(UIElement.Visibility)" Storyboard.TargetName="BackPanel">
                                        <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0:0:0" Value="Visible"/>
                                    </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                                </Storyboard>
                            </VisualState>
                        </VisualStateGroup>
                    </VisualStateManager.VisualStateGroups>
                    <StackPanel x:Name="Viewport" Height="400" Width="400">
                        <StackPanel.Projection>
                            <PlaneProjection x:Name="ViewportProjection" CenterOfRotationY="0.25"/>
                        </StackPanel.Projection>
                        <Grid x:Name="TitlePanel" Height="800" RenderTransformOrigin="0.5,0.5" Width="400">
                            <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                                <RowDefinition/>
                                <RowDefinition/>
                            </Grid.RowDefinitions>
                            <Grid.RenderTransform>
                                <CompositeTransform/>
                            </Grid.RenderTransform>
                            <Border Background="{TemplateBinding Background}" Grid.Row="0">
                                <TextBlock Foreground="{TemplateBinding Foreground}" FontSize="41" FontFamily="{StaticResource PhoneFontFamilyNormal}" LineStackingStrategy="BlockLineHeight" LineHeight="39" Margin="10,0,0,6" TextWrapping="NoWrap" Text="{TemplateBinding Title}" VerticalAlignment="Bottom"/>
                            </Border>
                            <Grid x:Name="BackPanel" Background="{TemplateBinding Background}" Height="400" Grid.Row="1" Visibility="Collapsed" Width="400">
                                <Grid.Projection>
                                    <PlaneProjection CenterOfRotationY="0.5" RotationX="180"/>
                                </Grid.Projection>
                                <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                                    <RowDefinition Height="*"/>
                                    <RowDefinition Height="Auto"/>
                                </Grid.RowDefinitions>
                                <TextBlock x:Name="NotificationBlock" Foreground="{TemplateBinding Foreground}" FontSize="{StaticResource PhoneFontSizeLarge}" FontFamily="{StaticResource PhoneFontFamilyNormal}" LineStackingStrategy="BlockLineHeight" LineHeight="32" Margin="8,8,0,6" Grid.Row="0" TextWrapping="NoWrap" Text="{TemplateBinding Notification}"/>
                                <TextBlock x:Name="MessageBlock" Foreground="{TemplateBinding Foreground}" FontSize="{StaticResource PhoneFontSizeNormal}" FontFamily="{StaticResource PhoneFontFamilyNormal}" LineStackingStrategy="BlockLineHeight" LineHeight="23.333" Margin="10,10,10,6" Grid.Row="0" TextWrapping="Wrap" Text="{TemplateBinding Message}"/>
                                <TextBlock x:Name="BackTitleBlock" Foreground="{TemplateBinding Foreground}" FontSize="{StaticResource PhoneFontSizeNormal}" FontFamily="{StaticResource PhoneFontFamilySemiBold}" Margin="10,0,0,6" Grid.Row="1" TextWrapping="NoWrap" VerticalAlignment="Bottom"/>
                            </Grid>
                            <Border x:Name="Image" Background="{TemplateBinding Background}" Grid.Row="1">
                                <Image Height="400" Source="{TemplateBinding Source}" Stretch="UniformToFill" Width="400"/>
                            </Border>
                        </Grid>
                    </StackPanel>
                </Border>
            </ControlTemplate>
        </Setter.Value>
    </Setter>
</Style>
```

You apply it like this:

```
<toolkit:HubTile Width="400" Height="400" 
                 Style="{StaticResource HubTileStyle1}" 
                 Background="Red" 
                 Source="/Assets/MedicineImg/crocin.jpg"
                 Title="Crocin"
                 HorizontalAlignment="Left"
                 VerticalAlignment="Top" />
```

It may need some tweaking, but it's a good start.

Comment: I clicked on edit a copy in VS 2012  and as per yr instructions changed 173 to 300 , but still only the frame enlarges not its contents . :-(

Comment: @varunsinghal65 did you look at the Style attached in the blog post?

Comment: Yes i did , in fact i had pasted that very same thing

Comment: @varunsinghal65 Obviously, things changed a lot since 2011. :) I edited my answer.